# How to view the downloaded files in Device ipad/iphone

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, download

Hi in my application i have option of downloading a pdf file i have searched for that i got the code i have used its working fine in my mac i can see the downloaded pdf file. But the problem is if i download the same pdf in device where i can find the downloaded pdf file in device.

This is my code which i have used to download the pdf file.

```
 NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jesusredeems.com/mag/pdf/JRE-2014-03.pdf"]]; //Store the Data locally as PDF File
 NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

 NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"11011.pdf"]; [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
```

If i print the filepath I'm getting like this.

```
/var/mobile/Applications/353C27AD-1E64-41CA-A429-16C2A20C8606/Documents/11011.pdf
```

In my mac i can see the downloaded file in that path but in my Ipad where i can see the downloaded pdf file please anyone tell where i have to find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your saving part is correct but try this anyways.

```
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://jesusredeems.com/mag/pdf/JRE-2014-03.pdf"]]; 

 NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES);
        NSString* documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *destPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"11011.pdf"];

 [pdfData writeToFile:destPath atomically:YES];
```

And do this to retrieve it.

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES);
    NSString* documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* dataFile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"11011.pdf"];
    NSData *pdfData3 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataFile];
```